# ¿Función para minutos?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Tengo una duda en una función ¿Alguien me puede ayudar a saber que es lo que hace?

```
private long TotalMinutos(DateTime fechaDate, DateTime fechaDate2)
{
    var st = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    TimeSpan fa = Convert.ToDateTime(fechaDate).ToUniversalTime() - st;
    TimeSpan fu = Convert.ToDateTime(fechaDate2).ToUniversalTime() - st;
    long mili1 = (long)fu.TotalMilliseconds;
    long mili2 = (long)fa.TotalMilliseconds;
    long total = mili2 - mili1;
    return (long)((total) / 1000 / 60);
}
```

Comment: alguna linea en particular ?

Comment: @LucianoMontañez el return

Comment: La operacion ((total) / 1000 / 60) son divisiones consecutivas, 
Solo esta casteando la operacion https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming/Casting

Comment: @LucianoMontañez entonces en realidad lo que nos regresa la funcion es el total de minutos que hay entre fa y fu?

Comment: Exacto, es la diferencia entre ambas fechas y por lo que parece, en milisegundos.

Comment: si, la diferencia en minutos.

Comment: no entiendo cual es el objetivo por el cual hay que restar una fecha en 1970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por bloques de código:

1.- Crea la fecha base: 1-1-1970

`var st = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);`

2.- Obtiene el número de segundos que han pasado desde el 1-1-1970 para la primera y segunda fecha.

`TimeSpan fa = Convert.ToDateTime(fechaDate).ToUniversalTime() - st;
TimeSpan fu = Convert.ToDateTime(fechaDate2).ToUniversalTime() - st;`

3.- Pasa las diferencias a milisegundos (es decir, obtiene los milisegundos que han pasado desde el 1-1-1970 hasta las fechas anteriores)

`long mili1 = (long)fu.TotalMilliseconds;
long mili2 = (long)fa.TotalMilliseconds;`

4.- Obtiene las diferencias en milisegundos entre fechas:

`long total = mili2 - mili1;`

5.- Pasa los milisegundos a minutos:

`return (long)((total) / 1000 / 60);`

Es decir: la función sirve para obtener la diferencia en minutos entre dos fechas.

Como decía otra respuesta, puedes sustituir toda la función por ésto:

`return (fechaDate.ToUniversalTime() - fechaDate2.ToUniversalTime()).TotalMinutes();`

Answer (score 2):

Esa funcionalidad se puede implementar mas simple si la idea es obtener la diferencia en minutos entre dos fechas.

Usa

[Datetime.Subtract()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/datetime-subtract-method-in-c-sharp/)

Para obtener el `TimeSpan` y de este la propiedad

[TimeSpan.TotalMinutes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalminutes?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Quedando algo como esto

```
private double TotalMinutos(DateTime fechaDate, DateTime fechaDate2)
{
    TimeSpan interval = fechaDate2.Substact(fechaDate);

    return interval.TotalMinutes;
}
```

Si quieres una respuesta como entero, usarias

```
long minutos = interval.Days * 24 * 60 +  interval.Hours * 60 + interval.Minutes;
```